# Verfiy a SMTP address is associated with a mailbox

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there any easy/elegant way to verify, that a SMTP address is associated with an Exchange mailbox via EWS?
Credentials of an administrative Exchange user are given.

**The following quick and dirty solution works:**
Create an ExchangeService with the SMTP address as Impersonated user
Try to make a method call
When the exception message is "The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it.", the SMTP address is not associated with a mailbox

**Problem:**
Not that elegant to compare the exception message
Takes about 200-250ms per user (not parallel)

**Another Problem:**
It is possible, that there are contacts in the GAL, that don't have a mailbox.
So ResolveNames won't be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the ResolveName operation and search the Directory you just need to prefix the address with smtp: and Exchange will the search both the Primary and proxyaddressses eg

```
String EmailAddresstoCheck = "info@domain.com";
NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName(("SMTP:" + EmailAddresstoCheck), ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true);
if (ncCol.Count == 1)
{
    if (ncCol[0].Contact != null)
    {
        if (EmailAddresstoCheck.ToLower() == ncCol[0].Mailbox.Address)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Primary SMTP Address of " + ncCol[0].Contact.DisplayName);
        }
        else                             
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy Address of " + ncCol[0].Contact.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("Primary SMTP Address : " + ncCol[0].Mailbox.Address);
        }                    
    }                
}
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is possible, that there are mail-addresses in the GAL, that don't have a mailbox. When the address is resolved against the GAL, it could give false positives.

Comment: You should be able to check the return type of the address which should be different for a Contact (eg oneoff) or add in an Autodiscover check in. The best way is test it yourself

Comment: The problem is, that there is no difference between the results. A contact even has the MailboxType Mailbox when it is not associated to a mailbox.

Comment: Then use AutoDiscover https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633699(v=exchg.80).aspx or use LDAP to look up Active Directory directly (or use the Graph API on Office365)

Comment: is there any elegant solution for the above problem using EWS or Graph API?

Comment: With the Graph you have full access to the directory so you can query the proxyaddresses like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=proxyAddresses/any(x:x eq 'smtp:gscales@blahblah.onmicrosoft.com')&$select=proxyAddresses